# Chainline issues

Tags: shimano, crankset, chainline

When my 10 year old chain snapped, I realized that I needed to replace my rear cassette and crank, due to wear. Noted for the future! I ordered a 9 speed cassette from Shimano (same brand and number of gears as I had), and a 3 speed front crank (again, same amount of gears and same brand, different type though: Shimano Altus M371). I thought I had taken all the factors into account, but of course I was wrong :). I noticed that I could not adjust my derailleur to smoothly shift gears without rubbing. I didn't know about the concept chainline, and I think it is very likely that my new crankset has a different chain line (50 mm) than my old one (unknown).

The problem that I have is that I can't find what chain line my old crank had. I think my options are either:

1. find out what chain line my old crank has, and try to find something similar. -> This seems very difficult, because most cranks I can order have 50mm (the same as the one I just bought)
2. play around with spacers. I am afraid this gets me into a rabbit hole. I don't exactly know what I need and I am afraid I will ruin something when I have to dissassemble my bottom bracket.

A picture to give it a little bit more context:
[image: Situation with new crankset]

Is this the moment to go to a bike shop? Or is there an easy fix that I could apply? I have a three piece crankset (I think it is Shimano Octolink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a square taper bottom bracket, which means there are no spacers that can help you. What you need is a bottom bracket with a longer spindle. Shimano recommends a BB-UN300 with a 123mm spindle for your crankset, so that's what I would get. Don't be afraid of changing your bottom bracket, it's not a complicated procedure and there's not really anything you can damage if you're careful and not cross-thread the BB into the shell.

[image]

Comment: +1, although "there's not really anything you can damage...". Not really accurate- plenty of people have come to grief as the left hand side is left threaded.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response! I think I can manage this repair :). Did they change this (recently?) for a reason? Perhaps I should stock up on cranks before the next time they decide to change a standard :)

Also, Is there a way to be sure my frame is compaitible with a axle length of 123mm? Naturally, my current bottom bracket is more narrow. Is there a system that keeps it from sliding to the sides?

Comment: The frame is compatible with any axle length, as long as the proper chainline is maintained (which is a function of spindle length and crank construction). Neither the axle nor the crankarms can slide to the side, if you tighten the crank bolt correctly.

Comment: Speaking of the crank bolt, the torque spec on the bolt is 40Nm, which is a quite a lot. If you don't own a torque wrench, you at least need a tool that can provide a lot of leverage: https://media.alltricks.com/hd/5166682271a21.jpg

Comment: Thanks again! I see the BN-UN300 123mm with a 68mm and a 73 mm box, I guess this is the width of the frame at the bottom bracket?

Comment: Exactly. It's called the bottom bracket shell. Measure yours and buy the correct size BB. Make sure to only measure the actual frame part, not including any protrusion from the bottom bracket.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it today :)